# Why would removing and adding back a Reference from a different location still reference the old location?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, reference, path, strongname

In trying to get a project to build in Visual Studio 2008, I am attempting to reference the DLLs that the project in XP Mode / Visual Studio 2003 uses (it compiles).

It's the same source code, so I thought the difference might be the DLLs the project references (I get err msgs like, "*[bla] not supported by the language*")

The System.Windows.Forms DLL referenced is version 1.0.5000.0 (Runtime Version "v1.1.4322")

I copied the DLLs from the XP Mode "machine" to a folder local to the Windows 7 machine. I am going through all the referenced DLLs in the project open in Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2008, first removing them and then adding back from the location where I copied the DLLs (from the XP machine to the W7 machine).

For the most part, this worked fine; but I've reached a set of DLLs that still reference the old path even after removing and adding back from the *other* location. Specifically, I:

```
(a) remove the DLL
(b) right-click "References" and select Add Reference
(c) In the "Browse" tab, select the DLL from the "new" folder/location
(d) select the "OK" button to add the DLL from the "new" folder/location
(e) Select the DLL below References to verify the Path property shows it pointing to the "new" folder/location
```

But no - it still points back to the previous Path - why would that be, and how can I remedy it?

In comparing property vals in the DLLs that work as expected, and those that don't, I see one variance: the "Strong Name" property is "True" where the path referencing works as desired, and it is "False" in the recalcitrant ones.

Is this the problem? If it is, how can I rectify it?

### UPDATE

The "Strong Name" value doesn't seem to be an/the issue - there is another DLL reference that also has "False" as its StrongName value, and yet I was able to Remove/Replace it...I don't think it could be anything to do with the specific DLLs, but they are the OpenNETCF* DLLs.

### UPDATE 2

Specifically, I get, for example: "*'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' does not contain a definition for 'SuspendLayout' and no extension method 'SuspendLayout' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*"

...and, on this line:

```
if (Util.StopCancel || Util.StopCancelRequested)
```

...this err msg: "*'HUtilCE.Util.StopCancelRequested' is not supported by the language*"

### UPDATE 3

Here's what I see when I open the recalcitrant DLL in dotPeek:

[image]

All its references *are* being referenced; all the other references now point to the same folder. For some reason the OpenNETCF* DLLs simply refuse to be pointed to that location, though. Does anybody have a clue why that would be?

Comment: Did you check if those dll are referenced in other dll you use?

Comment: How would I know if they are, and if they are, what could I do about it? Remove and add them back in a specific order, or...???